# CollectStatic выдает ошибку

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки! При попытке выполнить collectstatic, выносит статику в просто в корень диска D. Хотя с сетингсах прописал следующее:

В чем может быть проблема?

Settings:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    'D:\DjangoProjects\mysite']

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

Answer (score 0):

Переменная STATIC_ROOT принимает полный путь от корня системы.

Например:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 
# т.е. D:\DjangoProjects\mysite\static
```